# How to implement nice scrolling?

Tags: parallax, smooth-scrolling

I find it very hard to implement Nicescroll.js on my website, arcanova.no/hovsfjellet.html

I just want the scrolling to be smooth, not laggy like normal browser scrolls by default.For example: degernesleir.no scrolls smooth.

I have tried putting this on the end of my website:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        $("html").niceScroll();
    );
</script>
```

Here is a fiddle I tried to create, not sure if it is to any help.
https://jsfiddle.net/23v80a4w/

Any help out there? :)

Comment: How about creating a jsFiddle to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
I am not very skilled at coding, so I wont be able to create a helpful fiddle. According to the documentation of nicescroll, it seemed like I only had to download the files and include them in my html.

So this is what I did:
1. Downloaded the Nicescroll zip file. 2. Put them in my js folder. 3. Linked them from html. 4. No luck, still lagge scroll

Comment: @DaveIsak: I understand that you're not "skilled at coding", however, this website is not a community of people who will do it for you. The consensus is that you should provide a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and post it here for discussion. It is not acceptable to post a link and ask people to do your work.

Comment: I am sorry. Not trying to push my work on anybody else, just askin for help. https://jsfiddle.net/23v80a4w/ here is a fiddle :)